# Should anti CSRF token be refreshed on logout?

Tags: http, security, csrf

When a user logs out from a session-based site should their corresponding anti csrf token (stored in the session) be refreshed?

If the token should be refreshed then why specifically? Which possible vulnerabilities could bring not refreshing of the anti CSRF token?

Answer (score 1):

The official [OWASP advice](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Anti_CSRF_Tokens_ASP.NET) is that **yes**, the corresponding Anti-CSRF token *should* be refreshed, though there is actually little security benefit in doing so:

> Note that this value should be unique for every individual session. This guarantees that every form/request is tied to the authenticated user and, therefore, protected from CSRF. [...] The standard frequency of token generation is per-session, so make sure your sessions have a reasonable/configurable time-out. It is possible to issue new tokens on a per-request basis. However, the added protection may be insignificant, if this approach even fits your application.

**However**, the [linked StackExchange question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/why-refresh-csrf-token-per-form-request)'s accepted answer *does* have a security benefit if applied to anywhere with a principal change in the session stage (this is usually only on the login / log out) screen itself. This prevents a [session fixation attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation), where the attacker hijack's the victim's active session:

[image: Session Fixation]

This is done via cookie theft, client-side scripting, abusing the `<meta>` tag or through the HTTP headers. Resetting the anti-CSRF token during the login flow prevents this. However, note that a secondary token should only be applied at such points, as that there is a usability cost in terms of problems in using the back button and browsing in multiple tabs.